# Django - Heroku generates Celery migrations

Tags: django, heroku, celery

I have a Django app that works properly locally with the following

```
requirements:
Django==1.8.8
kombu==3.0.35
celery==3.1.23
django-celery==3.1.17
```

But when I deploy to Heroku and migrate I get the following message:

```
"Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied. Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.".
```

So I went ahead and run makemigrations locally but no new migrations were created. But if I run makemigrations in heroku I get:

```
Migrations for 'djcelery':
  0002_auto_20160527_1302.py:
    - Alter field status on taskmeta
    - Alter field state on taskstate.
```

I don't know why Heroku detects changes in djcelery app when it shouldn't.
Anyone has an idea of what might cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you get when you run `git status` locally?

Comment: The message I get is that everything is up to date.

On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: Try to remove `django-celery` and make your code work directly with `celery`. In recent versions of celery `django-celery` is not necessary to use celery with django